# Issue of large average intensity values while creating point pattern from a data frame using Spatstat in R

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I am using the Spatstat package in R for spatial point analysis. My dataset comprises location coordinates i.e. latitude and longitude of some event upto 6 places of decimal. It has some 9898 observations.

Here`s the output of the summary for the point pattern:

> Planar point pattern:  9898 points
>
> **Average intensity 149786.3 points per square unit**
>
> Coordinates are given to 6 decimal places
>
> units
>
> Window area = 0.0660808 square units

My question is that how can the Average Intensity value be so huge? Or is my approach of creating a point pattern is wrong? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a geographic coordinate system coordinates which spatstat doesn't support.

The coordinates are simply interpreted as units and since the window area is only 0.0660803 square units the point density is extrapolated to an average intensity of 149786.3 points per square unit.

Have a look at this thread how you convert (project) your coordinates to points on a flat map:

[Unit length in spatstat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35873254/unit-length-in-spatstat)