# Generating clustered spatstat marks for a ppp object

Tags: spatstat

This question is very close to what has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39398911/generate-clustered-spatstat-marks). The answer is great if we want to generate random marks to an already existing point pattern - we draw from a multivariate normal distribution and associate with each point.

However, I need to generate marks that follows the marks given in the `lansing` dataset that comes with `spatstat` for my own point pattern. In other words, I have a point pattern without marks and I want to *simulate* marks with a definite pattern (for example, to illustrate the concept of segregation for my own data). How do I make such marks? I understand the number of points could be different between `lansing` and my data set but I am allowed to reduce the window or create more points. Thanks!

Comment: I don't quite understand the big difference between this and the question you link to. You say you already have a point pattern and want to simulate marks. This is exactly the same for the linked question. Is the only difference that you want segregation and the other question was about clustering?

Comment: Yes, how do I make sure I will have segregation if I have clustering? Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: The point of my example answer below is that you have to be more specific about what you want. Do you want 6 patches where only one species lives or do you want 90% of one and 2% of each of the other? Should there be one patch per species or several? Should the patches be big/small? What about the shape of patches? Is it correct that you already have the points and you only want to attach random marks that appear in patches or do you also allow for the points to be generated randomly? Etc. etc.

Comment: Hi Ege, the point is to demonstrate how segregation works and it doesn't matter if the percentages are here and there. Let's say I want 4 patches with 30%, 20%, 10%, 40%, and I want one patch per species. How do I go about in simulating it? It is purely for demo purposes and the shape can be arbitrary  like some closed curves - rectangles are easy to generate. Yes, I already have the points and only want the marks. Marks are the only variable that I need to collect in my experiment.

Comment: I forgot to follow up on this. Now there is an alternative answer which you may find more appropriate. It should be straightforward to modify to your needs.

Comment: Very nice! I think you are making quadrats and generating marks with weighted distribution and merging them. This is really good. Thanks!

Besides this, I found the book to be very useful for my learning as well as for my course. I want to teach it as a one-semester course if possible and planning to introduce it in my curriculum. Thanks for making the subject accessible for lay people. Including the codes for several illustrations is a gem of an idea and makes it superior to other approaches.

Comment: I think we need to change the marks as a factor in the end to use multytype methods, such as `relrisk`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another version of segregation in four different rectangular
regions.

```r
library(spatstat)

p <- c(.6,.2,.1,.1)
prob <- rbind(p,
              p[c(4,1:3)],
              p[c(3:4,1:2)],
              p[c(2:4,1)])
X <- unmark(spruces)
labels <- factor(LETTERS[1:4])
subwins <- quadrats(X, 2, 2)
Xsplit <- split(X, subwins)
rslt <- NULL
for(i in seq_along(Xsplit)){
  Y <- Xsplit[[i]]
  marks(Y) <- sample(labels, size = npoints(Y),
                     replace = TRUE, prob = prob[i,])
  rslt <- superimpose(rslt, Y)
}
plot(rslt, main = "", cols = 1:4)
plot(subwins, add = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Segregation refers to the fact that one species predominates in a
specific part of the observation window. An extreme example would be to
segregate completely based on e.g. the x-coordinate. This would generate strips
of points of different types:

```r
library(spatstat)

X <- lansing
Y <- cut(X, X$x, breaks = 6, labels = LETTERS[1:6])
plot(Y, cols = 1:6)
```

[image]

Without knowing more details about the desired type of segregation it is
hard to suggest something more useful.

Comment: Yes Ege I get that. And I thought I can generate this segregation as well. I was looking for a more realistic example and I understand it's tough to generate.